# Fibonacci number code with for-loop and if statement error

Tags: c, for-loop, fibonacci, variable-length-array

so i'm a beginner and trying to solve a small project about making **fibonacci number**.
The code essentially is about typing *n* (the sequence) and it will show you what value of fibonacci number in that *n*-sequence.
but of course the code went wrong, the code just stop until i type the *n*-sequence, and nothing being printed after that. Can anybody check my code pls?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  int n;
  int seq[n];
  int i;

  printf("number of sequence for the fibonacci number that you want to find out (from 0)= ");
  scanf("%d", &n);

  for(i = 0; i <= n; i++){
    if(i == 0){
      seq[i] = 0;
    }
    else if(i == 1){
      seq[i] = 1;
    }
    else if(i > 1){
    seq[i] = seq[i-1] + seq[i-2];
    }
  }
  if(i == n){
    printf("the value in sequence %d is %d", n, seq[n]);
  }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int seq[n];` ==> `int seq[200];` if you want at most 200 numbers. Remember `n` is unassigned at this time (and you probably want to avoid *VLA*s anyway).

Comment: You need to put `int seq[n];` *after* you read `n` from the user.

Comment: the posted code results in the following message: *untitled.c:5:3: warning: ‘n’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare the variable length array seq after you entered its size

For example

```
  int n;
  int i;

  printf("number of sequence for the fibonacci number that you want to find out (from 0)= ");
  scanf("%d", &n);

  int seq[n + 1];
```

The size of the array is specified as n + 1 because the user is asked to enter the fibonacci number starting from 0.

Also this for loop will be correct provided that the array has n + 1 elements.

```
  for(i = 0; i <= n; i++){
```

It is better to write it like

```
  for(i = 0; i < n + 1; i++){
```

And this if statement

```
  if(i == n){
```

does not make a sense. Just output the value of the array element `seq[n]`.

Answer (score 1):

apparently, in the loop, you set the boarder as i<=n while the array seq[n] is with the size of n. So i must be less than n.

Answer (score 0):

1. `n` is uninitialized. It contains a garbage value.
2. Don't use `scanf()` for reading user input. It is very error-prone. Just try typing some string and see what happens. Better use `fgets()` in combination with `sscanf()`.

```c
int n;
char input[255];

printf("Number of sequence: ");
fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin);
input[strcspn(input, "\n")] = '\0';

if (sscanf(input, "%d", &n) != 1) {
    // Handle input error
}

int seq[n+1]; // Edited: n+1 because fib starts from 0 
int i;
for (i = 0; i < n+1; i++) {
    if (i == 0 || i == 1)
        seq[i] = i;
    else
        seq[i] = seq[i-1] + seq[i-2];
}
```

Comment: this is not valid: `for(i = 0; i = n; i++)` unlless 'n' is 0

Comment: @user3629249 I have edited my code. `i = n` was a typo. Thank you for pointing this out.